# Bloc borders with 4 images

Tags: css, html

i need to do something with some CSS but i really don't know how.

I need to have a bloc with images as border, but i need to have 4 images (top left bottom and right).

The problem is the left and right div's height must be equal to the center div.

If someone have a solution for this problem.

Thank you.
Cyril

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the sliding doors technique as outlined here

[Sliding doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/)

[Sliding doors part 2](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors2/)